# How can I create a second level domain name?

Tags: dns, web, subdomain

If I have a domain www.exemple.com how can I create second level domain ?

For exemple how can I create : 
Www.client1.exemple.com
Www.client2.exemple.com
...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will largely depend on who your domain name provider is. but basically the `client1` part of `www.client1.example.com` is a subdomain.

'Most' DNS providers will allow for the creation of subdomains but not all do.

Once you have created a subdomain then the `www` part of that is just another host

If you are aiming to have a system where you substitute anything for `client1` you might be able to use a www.*.example.com record. Again if your provider supports that (though they should do, it is standard DNS syntax) You would add the record www.* and it should match `www.$anything.example.com` This is useful if you have clients with subdomains instead of profiles and you just want to point them all to the same server.